# Best performance: $this->var Vs $_SESSION superglobal with big arrays

Tags: php, performance

I have a method that works with array with ~30000 entries. The method can be called usually about 100 times.

The idea is to use `$this->response` var and when the method is called another time save SQL querys...

Example:

```
function myMethod(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 30000";
            if(!isset($this->data_kpi))
                $this->data_kpi  = myclass::myPDOmethod($sql); //array entries

        //rest of method use $this->data_kpi
}
```

If I use a $_SESSION superglobal I get a best performance 6 Vs 19 seconds. I don't know why but i think is a bad practice use a superglobal for this....

Example with superglobal:

```
function myMethod(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 30000";
                if(!isset($_SESSION['tmp']))
                    $_SESSION['tmp']  = myclass::myPDOmethod($sql); //array entries

            //rest of method use $_SESSION['tmp']
}

 __destruct(){
    unset($_SESSION['tmp']);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sessions persist across requests, variables do not.

Comment: Yes, but $this-> persist inside the object. In this case myMethod() may be a private method called x number of times by other method. Both examples return exactly the same result but $_SESSION is up to 200% faster!.

Comment: I'm quite sure your benchmarks are wrong. Sessions are backed by filesystem or database or some such, but variables are in-memory entities

Comment: Your benchmarks must be making multiple requests, there is no way writing to persistent storage is going to be quicker than to memory.